# Set Python Indice

Tags: python

soy algo nuevo en Python. Necesito re-setar el índice con valores predeterminados. Algo así:

```
index    
0   
1
2
3
...
188
189
180
```

Necesito:

```
index    
-90   
-89
-88
-87
...
-1
 0
 1
...
 88
 89
 90
```

He estado intentando con reset_index. O haciendo una lista por separado y pegarla pero sin éxito.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir por favor el código de lo que has hecho hasta el momento? Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cree una lista, y luego la pegué:

```
indice = list(range(-90,91))
df.index = indice
```

Comment: ¿no te sirve hacer `df.index = list(range(-90, 01))`?